# Is this a suitable scenario to use polymorphic association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My scenario is:

Order has many items
item belongs to order

And,
item can be a product or a spare.

So in this case , instead of using product_id and spare_id and having nil values , can i use polymorphic association ? i.e There is a type feild, if the type product is selected then the type_id will hold product, if type is spare then the type_id should hold spare.
Is the thought of using polymorphic association in this scenario right?

Comment: Hi, in this case i can just select if its product or spare but not slect which product or spare i want to order right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually for cases mixing of items use *STI* (with type field for an item) it will differ `Product` from `Spare` for you, so

```
class Item < AR:Base
   belongs_to :order
   # has_field :type
end

class Spare < Item; end
class Product < Item ;end
```

and you can select product or spare, or even item, like:

```
Product.all
Spare.all
Item.all
```